# EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22

Tags: boot, 22.04, lts

I was using Ubuntu 20.04 which worked perfectly until I received the update notice, and now that I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, I cannot boot my pc properly as it displays a black screen with the following lines:

```
cblk0p2: recovering journal
cblk0p2: clean, 441893/1875968 files, 6007681/7502336 blocks

[..229] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22
[..235] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22
```

How can I fix this?

**P.s:** I would like to point out that I used a command to access Ubuntu previous version but now it's stuck on a black screen with a white dash on the left top side of the screen.

Thank you!